Adding variables to an API payload with new lines in Python
I am pretty new to Python, and what I'm trying to achieve is to add variables to the payload below in Python; it's meant for Zeptomail API, and I'm trying to customize and add user-specific data to the payloads 'merge info' and the 'to' header before sending the email template.
example.py
test_name = 'users name'
test_email = 'users@email.test'
test_title = 'users title'

payload = '''
    {
        \n\"mail_template_key\":\"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\",

        \n\"from\": {
            \"address\": \"example@mail.com\",
            \"name\": \"example\"
            },

        \n\"to\": [{
            \"email-address\": {
                \"address\": \"test_email\",
                \"name\": \"test_name\"
                }
            }],

        \n\"merge_info\": {
            "name":"test_name",
            "title":"test_title"
            }}
'''

I'm expecting to print out a new payload variable with the included user-specific, 'test_' values in place.
expected print(),
payload = '''
    {
        \n\"mail_template_key\":\"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\",

        \n\"from\": {
            \"address\": \"example@mail.com\",
            \"name\": \"example\"
            },

        \n\"to\": [{
            \"email-address\": {
                \"address\": \"users@email.test\",
                \"name\": \"users name\"
                }
            }],

        \n\"merge_info\": {
            "name":"users name",
            "title":"users title"
            }}
'''


Is your question related to newlines (\n) or about putting the value of variables (e.g. test_name) into the payload string? What do you expect print(payload) to output?

Hi, I'm expecting to print out the payload with the included variables at the top.

Sorry, I wasn't clear. Please edit your question and type in the exact string output you expect to see.

Does this answer your question? Putting a variable into a string (quote)

Thanks a lot for your prompt reply. I just saw the post you suggested; I'm aware of how to format strings also how to iterate through json data, but in this case; the only thing that throws me off is the new lines in this context

I am quite new to all this, but to my understanding and through a bit of research, I would assume that I should convert this payload value to a JSON dictionary, update the intended data, and then maybe switch it back to its original new line form with the updated data. But I'm not sure how to achieve that either

The payload is JSON-formatted, so simply build a Python object of dicts/lists, then convert to a JSON string:
import json

test_name = 'users name'
test_email = 'users@email.test'
test_title = 'users title'

data = {'mail_template_key': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        'from': {'address': 'example@mail.com',
                 'name': 'example'},
        'to': [{'email-address': {'address': test_email,
                                  'name': test_name}}],
        'merge_info': {'name': test_name,
                       'title': test_title}}

payload = json.dumps(data, indent=2)  # indent for pretty-printing, an API doesn't need it.
print(payload)

Output:
{
  "mail_template_key": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "from": {
    "address": "example@mail.com",
    "name": "example"
  },
  "to": [
    {
      "email-address": {
        "address": "users@email.test",
        "name": "users name"
      }
    }
  ],
  "merge_info": {
    "name": "users name",
    "title": "users title"
  }
}

If you need to update the existing payload string you have, convert it from JSON, patch the fields, and convert it back to JSON:
import json

test_name = 'users name'
test_email = 'users@email.test'
test_title = 'users title'

payload = '''
    {
        \n\"mail_template_key\":\"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\",

        \n\"from\": {
            \"address\": \"example@mail.com\",
            \"name\": \"example\"
            },

        \n\"to\": [{
            \"email-address\": {
                \"address\": \"users@email.test\",
                \"name\": \"users name\"
                }
            }],

        \n\"merge_info\": {
            "name":"users name",
            "title":"users title"
            }}
'''

data = json.loads(payload)
data['to'][0]['email-address']['address'] = test_email
data['to'][0]['email-address']['name'] = test_name
data['merge_info']['name'] = test_name
data['merge_info']['title'] = test_title

payload = json.dumps(data, indent=2)
print(payload)  # same output as above


Thank a whole lot. Will this still work even without the new lines like you've illustrated?

@Raymond Yes, APIs don't care about the whitespace around the values.

@Raymond I'll update with an example loading your existing string and updating the data in-place as well.

That would be very helpful @Mark.
